# Groupby in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Consider the following dataset:

```
a        b
0        23
0        21
1        25
1        20
1        19
2        44
2        11
```

How can I  find the percentages of values in column b which are greater than 20 ,and are in the same cluster according to column a.
my code give me the same value for each group.

```
NN20 = [x for x in b if (x > 20)]
percent_20 = lambda x: float(len(NN20)) / float(len(b))
pnn20=data.groupby('a').apply(percent_20)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IIUC:

```
In [179]: df.groupby('a')['b'].apply(lambda x: x.gt(20).mean())
Out[179]:
a
0    1.000000
1    0.333333
2    0.500000
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

or

```
In [183]: df.groupby('a')['b'].transform(lambda x: x.gt(20).mean())
Out[183]:
0    1.000000
1    1.000000
2    0.333333
3    0.333333
4    0.333333
5    0.500000
6    0.500000
Name: b, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Why do you use mean instead of sum/len?

Comment: @AlterNative, it gives us the same result, but it's nicer, shorter and requires less operations... PS actually `mean(lst) == sum(lst) / len(lst)` ;-)

Answer (score 2):

If you need something fast, [`np.bincount`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.bincount.html) could be a good solution instead of a Pandas groupby.

```
np.bincount(df.loc[df.b > 20, 'a']) / np.bincount(df.a))
```

which returns

```
array([ 1.        ,  0.33333333,  0.5       ])
```

Or if you wanted to transform the output back to a series, you could subsequently use [`np.take`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.take.html).

```
pd.Series((np.bincount(df.loc[df.b > 20, 'a']) / np.bincount(df.a)).take(df.a))

# 0    1.000000
# 1    1.000000
# 2    0.333333
# 3    0.333333
# 4    0.333333
# 5    0.500000
# 6    0.500000
# dtype: float64
```

---

In either case, this seems to be quite fast.

**Smaller case: provided dataset**

*`groupby` approach from MaxU*

```
%timeit df.groupby('a')['b'].transform(lambda x: x.gt(20).mean())
2.51 ms ± 65.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

*`np.bincount` approach*

```
%timeit pd.Series((np.bincount(df.loc[df.b > 20, 'a']) / np.bincount(df.a)).take(df.a))
271 µs ± 5.28 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

**Larger case: generated dataset**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': np.random.randint(0, 10, 100000), 
                   'b': np.random.randint(0, 100, 100000)}).sort_values('a')
```

*`groupby` approach from MaxU*

```
%timeit df.groupby('a')['b'].transform(lambda x: x.gt(20).mean())
11.3 ms ± 40.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

*`np.bincount` approach*

```
%timeit pd.Series((np.bincount(df.loc[df.b > 20, 'a']) / np.bincount(df.a)).take(df.a))
1.56 ms ± 5.47 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way to do it (added another value for 0%):

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'a': [0,0,1,1,1,2,2,3],
                     'b': [23,21,25,20,19,44,11,15]})

data['c'] = data['b'].apply(lambda x: int(x>20))
shareOf20 = data.groupby('a')['c'].sum() / data.groupby('a')['c'].count()
```